# Vertical align top list elements which span 2 lines and fly outs to align with drop menu items

Tags: html, css

Im trying to vertically align my top menu items in the middle, ive tried line-height but because they span 2 lines this will not work. Also when I add a 3rd level to the list the fly out menu is not aligned with the corresponding parent list item. http://jsfiddle.net/pk8Lm/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li class="rhombusStart">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Market <br> Update</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Team Membership</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>FISC Info</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">About the FISC</a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">International</a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href="#"><img class = "arrow" src="Images/arrow.png" alt="&#9658;">Advantages of listing</a> 
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Advantages of Listing</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Products</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href ="#">Links</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">About US</a></li>
                     <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Details</a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">Location</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="rhombusEnd">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/*******************************************
 Menu Styling
*******************************************/
#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 2%;
    width: 640px;
    height: 3.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    border: 1px solid rgb(140,51,61);
}
#nav {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
     height:3.5em;
     background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
     display: table;
}

#nav ul {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
     background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
}

#nav a.linkchild:link,
#nav a.linkchild:active,
#nav a.linkchild:visited {
    display:block;
    padding:0px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #b95d73; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%, #970e2e 0%, #9c1a38 0%, #910022 52%, #b95d73 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b95d73), color-stop(0%,#970e2e), color-stop(0%,#9c1a38), color-stop(52%,#910022), color-stop(100%,#b95d73)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#970e2e 0%,#9c1a38 0%,#910022 52%,#b95d73 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#970e2e 0%,#9c1a38 0%,#910022 52%,#b95d73 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#970e2e 0%,#9c1a38 0%,#910022 52%,#b95d73 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#970e2e 0%,#9c1a38 0%,#910022 52%,#b95d73 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b95d73', endColorstr='#b95d73',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
}

#nav a.rhlink:link, #nav a.rhlink:active, #nav a.rhlink:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

#nav li.rhombus:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#B95D73), color-stop(25%, #9C1A38), color-stop(50%, #970E2E), color-stop(75%, #910022), to(#B95D73)); 
    background: #b95d73; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%, #9c1a38 25%, #970e2e 50%, #910022 75%, #b95d73 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b95d73), color-stop(25%,#9c1a38), color-stop(50%,#970e2e), color-stop(75%,#910022), color-stop(100%,#b95d73)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#9c1a38 25%,#970e2e 50%,#910022 75%,#b95d73 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#9c1a38 25%,#970e2e 50%,#910022 75%,#b95d73 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#9c1a38 25%,#970e2e 50%,#910022 75%,#b95d73 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #b95d73 0%,#9c1a38 25%,#970e2e 50%,#910022 75%,#b95d73 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b95d73', endColorstr='#b95d73',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a.linkchild:hover {
   background: rgb(118,0,18);
   color: white;
}

#nav > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#nav > li.rhombus {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:skew(35deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(35deg);
    transform:skew(35deg);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(239,89,24);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(255,244,80);
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 3.5em;
}
#nav > li.rhombusStart {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:skew(35deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(35deg);
    transform:skew(35deg);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(239,89,24);
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    width: 1em;
    height: 3.5em;

}
#nav > li.rhombusEnd {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(35deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(35deg);
    -o-transform: skew(35deg);
    transform: skew(35deg);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(255,244,80);
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    width: 1em;
    height: 3.5em;
}   

li.rhombus > a span {
    -webkit-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(-35deg);
    transform:skew(-35deg);
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;     
 }

li.rhombus > ul {
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform:translate(0,1px) skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(-35deg);
    transform:skew(-35deg);
}

#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:3.5em;
    left:0;
    width:15em;
    display:none;
}

#nav li ul a {
    width:15em;
    float:left;
    border-bottom: 1px, solid, rgb(145,0,34);
    border-top: 1px, solid, rgb(178,77,101);
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell; 
}

#nav ul ul {
    top:auto;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    left:15em;
    margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    display:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul,
#nav li li:hover ul,
#nav li li li:hover ul,
#nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

img.arrow 
{
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to support IE6, do:

- remove display: table from #nav
- add display: table to the main li elements with links inside them (the ones you want to center).
- add display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle to the main links inside the li elements.

And then fiddle around with the looks.

Comment: Tried this with no success :(

Comment: You just have some css rules overwriting others. http://jsfiddle.net/pk8Lm/2/ I used !important hack to show that it works.

Comment: Thankyou so much!,How did you get they fly out to be in the correct position? And is there a way to get the text aligned in the centre? Ive tried adding to the a span with no success.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "fly out to be in the correct position" but you can align the text to center by making the span into block level element and applying text-align: center; to it. http://jsfiddle.net/pk8Lm/3/

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate all this help. By fly out I mean the menus that pop out to the side of the drop downs they weren't aligned but now are perfect.